# How to update pytorch model with supervision provided by caffe model?

Tags: caffe, pytorch, pycaffe

I want to do something like this:

```
# pytorch_model to train, caffe_model freezed
torch_out = pytorch_model(input)
caffe_out = caffe_model(torch_out)
loss = criterion(caffe_out, label)
loss.backward() # or something like torch_out.backward()
```

I can easily get the gradient of torch_out provided by caffe_model.backward(), but how can I update pytorch_model with that?

Comment: what parameters are you giving the optimizer?

Comment: @Shai only pytorch_model to train, caffe_model is freezed

Comment: are both `pytorch_model` and `caffe_model` `nn.Module` subclasses?

Comment: @Shai no, caffe_model is `*.caffemodel` & `*.prototxt`, which is loaded by pycaffe